Manhwa where the world becomes a game with goblins and bosses like minotaurs, but the main character is playing for the second time
Manhwa where the world becomes a game and goblins pour out and bosses like minotaurs, etc, but the main character is playing for the second time and saves people he couldn't save before.

In roughly which year did you read this?

This is like super tropey.  It's probably set in the modern world, so what country?  Does everyone have the game system installed, or just people who were playing before, or is there a caste of players/heroes/hunters?

This is likely Only I Know the World Is Ending And Getting Killed by Rampaging Beasts Only Makes Me Stronger, also identified here.

Akira Ichijo is your average, run-of-the-mill businessman. One day, on his way home from work, he is suddenly attacked by a Minotaur and killed on the spot. But in the blink of an eye...he wakes up back at the office! When monsters invade into the real world, a cruel reality sets in as the world as we know it plummets into destruction and death. But with the unique skill, "Resurrection," Akira can come back to life every time he dies, all the while inheriting the same levels and skills from his last run at life!

The synopsis includes the minotaur; he also fights goblins later on. Coming back to life would count as "playing for the second time".

He fights a goblin and manages to kill it, but dies again in the process. This still gives him a level up from the kill, plus a bonus achievement for his first kill - he continually uses these boosts to get stronger.
This includes fighting a huge horde of goblins within a shop.

